# Storing a compressed image

Tags: java, android

I am able to save an image in my internal storage but I am unable to store the compressed one.

**This is my java code**

I have used getFileUri() to store the image in Pictures directory of the phone and I am using getimage bytes() to compress the file but I am not getting any error nor am I able to compress the image. I am able to save the normal image but I am unable to save the compressed on.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Button button, buttonCompress;
    private String encoded_string, image_name;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ImageView img;
    private File file;
    private Uri file_uri;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    Intent data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);//For writing into internal storage.

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCam);
        buttonCompress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnComp);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonCompress.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnCam:
                Intent intentCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                getFileUri();
                intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file_uri);
                startActivityForResult(intentCamera, 10);
                break;
            case R.id.btnComp:
                getImageBytes(img);
                getFileUri();
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            img.setImageURI(file_uri);
            Log.d("path is", file.getPath());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Written !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void getFileUri() {
        image_name = "picture1.jpg";
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                + File.separator + image_name
        );
        file_uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Log.d("uri is", file_uri.toString());
    }


    private byte[] getImageBytes(@NonNull ImageView imageView) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

**This my XML file**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="257dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="32dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="98dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCam"
    android:layout_width="94dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:text="Camera"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="448dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="145dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnComp"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:text="compress"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-9dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-5dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnCam"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView" />
```

Comment: The method getFileUri() is supposed to store the Image in storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picture1.jpg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't written the code to save it. Try the below code to get the image from imageview, compress it and then save it in your storage directory. hope it will work for you.

```
Bitmap bitmapsave = null;
       //get image bitmap from imageview 
        bitmapsave = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();


       //create folder where you want to store compressed image
       File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "/yourAppname");
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
            // name that image
            String filename = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try
    {
        out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        bitmapsave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out);
        out.close();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: the method in getFIleUri() is supposed to store the Image in the storage.

Comment: That I saw but you are not storing compressed image bytes in that method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  ..

```
private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {
    if(image == null){
        return;
    }
    try {
        File pictureFile = new File ("your_path");

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fos);
        fos.close();
        Log.e(TAG,"FILE created");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"Excetion in image storage "+e.toString());
    }
}
```